# Weblogic vs Apache load balancer

Tags: apache, jakarta-ee, architecture, weblogic, load-balancing

In our typical production environment, Apache web server works as proxy to our application server like weblogic. I have question about load balancing. Both apache and web logic provide its own functionality of load balancing. If apache can balance the load, what is the use of web logic load balancer.

Comment: Are you asking just out of curiosity or have a particular issue to solve?

Comment: I am supposed to do it for one of my project. That is the reason I posted this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the oracle doc [Load Balancing](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/cluster/load_balancing.html), there are many ways of doing load balancing for weblogic. Should you already have an Apache web server, it is better to use that instead of having Weblogic do the load balancing. The load balancer must typically be off the JVM because the should there be higher traffic, weblogic must have reserve resources for these incidents. Apache does load balancing very easily but weblogic requires more effort as it is an additional feature. Its basically like a boat in water and a car that can also float (the car being weblogic).